# My Android Emulator is Too Slow..Also RAM difficulties

Tags: android, sdk, android-emulator

I have recently started to learn android development.. so i downloaded this adt-bundle
I use Windows 7 32-bit.. so as I installed I set two emulators..
One of the emulator is : 
Nexus 4, API 18 (4.3), CPU Intel Atom(x86)
so when I set the ram to 1507.. it shows warning that windows can't support it so.. my first question is, is it any possible to set to a higher ram.. then I set it to 768..so it does not show any problem.. after I save it and try to launch it .. a black screen comes up where it is written android which is showing it is loading.. but it never opens..

Other emulator is : 
5.1"WVGA API 10(2.3.3), CPU Intel Atom(x86)
so the Ram is automatically below 768...I save it and launched it and it perfectly showed up..but it is too slow..

I really don't know how to solve this problem..so please help me..I am doing a course on Coursera.org.. I am following that.. but when I posted this problem to the forum i got no answer.. but I hope to  get help from here..

Comment: possible duplicate of [Slow Android emulator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1554099/slow-android-emulator)

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem. I can recommend you [GENYMOTION](http://www.genymotion.com/) emulator. Is much more faster and you will not have problems with ram

Answer (score 0):

If you have a Intel CPU take a look at this:
http://www.developer.com/ws/android/development-tools/haxm-speeds-up-the-android-emulator.html

Answer (score 0):

You can speed up the emulator by downloding the following from the ANDROID SDK Manager

```
 Intel X86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM)
```